# Finite Calculus on undefinded values -- Concrete Mathematics

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I have been reading Concrete Mathematics by Donald Knuth.  Upon reading chapter 2 on page 29, I came across the following sum : $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}=$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$.

From this I deduce that $H_n$ is defined for any integer $\geq 1$.

However, on page 56, we have the following:
$\sum_{}^{} xH_x \delta x = \frac{x^{\underline2}}{2}H_x - \frac{x^{\underline2}}{4} + C$ and that $\sum_{0}^{n-1} kH_k = \sum_{0}^{n} xH_x \delta x =\frac{n^{\underline2}}{2}(H_n - \frac{1}{2})$.

That is, $\frac{x^{\underline2}}{2}H_x - \frac{x^{\underline2}}{4} + C \bigg|_{0}^{n} = \frac{n^{\underline2}}{2}(H_n - \frac{1}{2})$.

But this last line requires us to compute $(\frac{n^{\underline2}}{2}H_n - \frac{n^{\underline2}}{4} + C) - (\frac{0^{\underline2}}{2}H_0 - \frac{0^{\underline2}}{4} + C)$. But $H_0$ is not defined.  So how can we correctly compute this last line?

Comment: One can even [define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments) $H_n$ for $0\le n\le 1$, and from there for other fractional values for $n$.

Comment: I don't think I am good enough at mathematics yet to understand what is happening in this link. But thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a natural way to define $H_0$ according to the definition of $H_n$.  A summation like $\sum_{k=1}^0 \frac{1}{k}$ makes sense: you are adding up $\frac{1}{k}$ for all values of $k$ such that $1\leq k\leq 0$.  There are no such values of $k$, so you are adding up no numbers.  When you add up no numbers, you get $0$, so $H_0=0$.

Comment: Just to make sure, we are allowed to say that $H_0 = 0$ because $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that.  We never need to consider $\frac{1}{0}$, because $k=0$ does not satisfy $1\leq k\leq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that mathematics is a literal art.